# PositionList error removing elements

Tags: java, list

I have a problem with an algoritm in Java.
This algoritm have to remove elements from a list, but only one time (the first element).
I tried this, i compile good but problems when i run it...

```
    /**
 * Returns in "list" the previous content of "list" after removing "subList" if it is present in "list"
 *
 * @param  list     (input/output)  The list where search and remove the first occurrence of "subList"
 * @param  subList  (input)         The sub list to search within "list"
 */

public void removeSubList(PositionList<E> list,PositionList<E> subList) {
    Position<E> cursor1 = list.first();
    Position<E> cursor2 = subList.first();
    while(cursor1 != null && cursor2 != null)
        if(cursor1.element()==cursor2.element()){
            Position<E> borrar = cursor1;
            cursor1=list.next(cursor1);
            cursor2=list.next(cursor2);
            list.remove(borrar);
        }


}
```

This is what i want on the console output:

removeSubList([3,2,3,4,5,3],[3])[2,3,4,5,3]

removeSubList([2,3,4,5,3,4],[3,4])-------->  [2,5,3,4]

removeSubList([3,2,3,4,7],[3,7])-------->  [3,2,3,4,7]

removeSubList([3,2,3,4,5,3],[])-------->  [3,2,3,4,5,3]

removeSubList([],[3,7])-------->  []

removeSubList(null,[3,7])-------->  null

removeSubList([3,2,3,4,5,3],null)-------->  [3,2,3,4,5,3]

Only remove the first.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What kind of problems? Explain please

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I want to ask a question:
is this output right?

```
removeSubList([3,2,3,4,7],[3,7])--------> [3,2,3,4,7]
```

shouldn't it be [2,3,4] ?

Well, lets look on that code:

```
 while(cursor1 != null && cursor2 != null)
    if(cursor1.element()==cursor2.element()){
        Position<E> borrar = cursor1;
        cursor1=list.next(cursor1);
        cursor2=list.next(cursor2);
        list.remove(borrar);
    }
```

1. If elements are equal then you are selecting the next one, but when they are not what then, infinite loop? You should always get the next element, not only when the elements are equal.
2. I'm not sure that '==' is the best method to check is something equal to something, try .equals() instead.
3. Next thing is, you shouldn't modify (especially delete something from) the list you are iterating through. Please create new list that will be your result list.

Please fix these things and if you will have further problems please describe them and write outputs you are getting.

Comment: Yes, my fail the output of that: removeSubList([3,2,3,4,7],[3,7])--------> [3,2,3,4,7] should be [2,3,4]

Comment: How can I use equals there? This can be do easier with for?